# How to Format / Highlight cells that do not contain any number

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

For our address label printer we use an Excel file.
Unfortunately in Holland many people forget to add their house number and I'm trying to fill them with red so our team knows they need to contact them to get their house number.

Here is an example:
https://gyazo.com/89a0f89542b2256efdda45c7dec00ce4

As you see in cell D9. somebody forgot to enter a house number, so that cell should be filled red.

I googled a lot, but could not find the correct conditional formatting answer for it.

Comment: Test for a blank.

Comment: Or use a filter to copy your list of incomplete addresses for your team.

Comment: Please be aware that it is entirely possible in The Netherlands to have addresses without a house number (it isn't very common, but it is possible), or where the house number is not actually a number. As an aside, your screenshot seems to be leaking actual personal data, and that is a GDPR violation, which means your company will now have to notify these customers and the Autoriteit Persoonsgegevens.

Comment: Also, there are addresses where the street name contains a number (or the street name is entirely a number, I believe Lelystad or maybe Almere has a number of those), so checking isn't necessarily that simple.

Comment: You should remove this data immediately -> see comment by @mark-rotteveel

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You are absolutly right. Now blurred them out.
I am aware that there are addresses without numbers, it is just to highlight so our team can be aware that the # might be missing

Comment: @SolarMike that won't work as the street name + number are in the same cell so it will never be blank

Comment: Well there are q&a on here showing the use of regex. One will likely show you enough and you can then edit it to suit.

Comment: @Luuk You may want to consider deleting the image at the old link, and/or flag for moderation attention to scrub the old link from the edit history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find if string contains any number you can use this formula:

```
=COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},D1))>0
```

It returns `TRUE` if there is a number and `FALSE` otherwise.

Since you can't use arrays in conditional formatting you have to use this formula in "helper column", then you can use output (TRUE and FALSE) in conditional formatting.

Comment: Given there are street names that contain numbers, or addresses where the house number is not actually a number, this approach will not work for all addresses.

Comment: In most European Excel country versions this does not work. Comma's are used as decimal separators. Use the backslash "\" in stead of the comma.See example:  =COUNT(FIND({0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9};B2))>0

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by [Solar Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4961700/solar-mike), this is fairly easy indeed, you just need to create a conditional formatting rule, based on the `=ISBLANK()` function, as shown here:

[image]

(The `G3` in the formula refers to the top left cell.)

Comment: This won't work as the streetname and number are in the same cell. Ergo the cell will never be blank